# Is the $I^2R$ when a resistive heating element is cool the same as when it's hot?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, electricity

My system (electric resistance element and water bath) heats up 2 degrees in 20 seconds (0.1 deg/sec) when the resistance element if fully heated.

Say I want to raise the temperature 0.1 deg every few seconds to counteract cooling, can I just turn on the heater for one second, even though the element won't be $I^2R$ when the resistive heating element is cool the same as when it's hot (inrush v. steady-state)?  Will the same amount of energy transfer?

If not, what's the fudge factor?

Comment: I think you're looking for [information about the temperature coefficient of resistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature_coefficient).

Comment: Assuming $R$ is temperature invariant, $P=I^2R$ always applies. $R$ usually does depend on $T$ somewhat. It's material dependent, see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantan

Answer (score 1):

Resistance varies with temperature.  This can lead to significant design issues in high power applications, requiring cooling.  For resistive heating the "working" resistance is the one matched with the working current: the control parameter is the power dissipation, due to joule heating.

So if you want to model the heater/cooling bath system, it requires knowledge of the resistance-temperature curve.  I have used this type of information in order to protect solenoids from overheating by monitoring the coil resistance.